# My stickers on the app store are not being animated

Tags: ios

When I test my sticker pack with the similator in x code, they are animated, but when I download them on my phone they are not animated. Why is that??? 
They used to be animated normally but now they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 10.3.3 doesn't support playing for large gifs. Make sure your images are less than 300K.

Comment: It used to be less than 500k. What happened exactly? Also does that mean that there are no animated stickers now? Because my othet app still works fine and it is animated.

Comment: 500k is critical size to compile and show without warnings. But now we have one more limitation - for playing. The information is not from official documentation. I found this experimentally when faced with the same problem. All gifs and apngs < 300K were playing well, all other looked static.

Comment: The app is called animated monument stickers. The other is called national flags animated. They both have the same sizes in general when it comes down to each sticker. Why would one work and the other not??

Comment: Sorry, but I have no answer. Maybe, the reason is in different versions of xcode you used to build these apps, maybe in Moon phases. Apple guys keep silence.